# NOAA nautical chart tileset integration with leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I am hoping to use the NOAA nautical charts [tileset](https://tileservice.charts.noaa.gov/tileset.html#50000_1-locator) as a base map in a leaflet map made with R.

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% 
addTiles() #use NOAA chart tiles here
```

I am hopeful that one can just use the tile URL as suggested by [leaflet](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/basemaps.html). I am just not sure how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing is coming to mind yet, but I am looking at these two sources: 1) downloading the shape files into your working directory (https://tileservice.charts.noaa.gov/tileset.html#50000_1-arcgisguide); and 2) possibly calling the tiles through an API (https://owi.usgs.gov/blog/basemaps/). Hope this helps someone offer a solution!

Comment: Thanks. Got the connection to my local ArcGIS, and that is helpful regardless of the leaflet issue.Maybe there is a way to connect the Arc and R/leaflet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% 
   addTiles(urlTemplate = '//tileservice.charts.noaa.gov/tiles/50000_1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')  #use NOAA chart tiles here
```